# Variance of a random vector (different of the covariance matrix)

Tags: probability, variance, covariance-matrix

Tipically, the variance of a p-dimensional random vector
$$X = (X_1,...,X_p)$$

is defined as a the covariance matrix given by:
$$E[ (X- EX)^T(X- EX)  ]$$

But, in the second page of this [paper](https://www.ism.ac.jp/editsec/aism/pdf/007_2_0081.pdf), the variance of $X$ is defined as:
$$v(X)= E|X - EX|^2$$

I've never seen this definition and I would like to know more about this definition.

Some help?

Comment: It's the same definition. The absolute value notation means vector norm

Comment: @J.Delaney I don't think so. This paper, as is allowable in any mathematical paper, defines and names terms as it wishes.  It distinguishes the "covariance matrix" (see the top of p. 83) from the "variance" and clearly indicates its "variance" is as stated: the expected squared length of $X$ relative to its mean. The assertion (also on p. 83) that "the variance $v$ is given by $v = \operatorname{tr} \sigma + \kappa(R_p)$" is particularly revealing, insofar as $\sigma$ is a matrix of the same dimensions as the covariance matrix $s$ and the trace is explicitly a scalar.

Comment: @whuber I believe your comment makes a very good answer for the question

Comment: Yes, according the paper, the variance definition is a sclar. I ended up not posting this information.

Comment: @whuber right it looks like they define the variance to be the trace of the covariance matrix. my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this $v(X)$ is the sum $\sum_i Var(X_i),$ so $v(X)$ is just the trace of the covariance matrix. I think that mathematically $v(X)$ makes a lot of sense and it is basically a measure of how much $X$ is different from a constant random vector. Of course, we could also consider other analogues quantities like the determinant of the covariance matrix or its norm, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In the first page, they define $|x|=\sqrt{x'x}$, which yields
$$v(X)=E[(X-E[X])^T(E-E[X])]$$
which seems like it's same as yours; but it's not, because the paper uses its own variance definition and vector dimensions.

Comment: I don't think so: be careful with the transposes.  The distinct is between a *scalar* and a $p\times p$ *matrix.*

Comment: oops, thank you!